# Retrieve an html page from history?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8, cache, history

1. I was looking at a very important page, and then the server disconnected and the page is gone
2. I went offline and shut my internet browser

Is the page stored somewhere locally so I can go and load it?

Comment: Was it a video or static html content ?

Comment: Static html content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

If the problem is your connection, or it's the server's connection and you get an error page from your browser (only if the server didn't propose a different page, which then the browser updates the cache, which you go to other solution bellow), then from the File menu (Press Alt to reveal the menu) click 'Work Offline' (also available from the Tools menu in the command bar), then follow the instructions on [Al Everett's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/160506/retrieve-an-html-page-from-history/160508#160508) to find the desired page.

[image: Work offline]

If you have a connection to the Internet but somehow the server is off and you don't have the page in the cache then there is another useful way I just found - loading the page from Google Search results' cached pages:

[image: Cached]

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> is the default key combo to pull up your browser history. Unless the page you were viewing prevented caching and/or was dynamic, you should be able to get back to it.

Comment: I tried the above but the page is not retrieved offline.

Comment: As I said, if the page was dynamic, or if the site prevented caching, or if it's behind a login, or it requires a form submission, you're likely not going to get back to it.

Comment: The page is definitely not dynamic. it's a static html page, and caching is not disabled. The connection between the server and me is down (either server's problem either my problem).